# Exclude specific rules SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, rule, owasp

Is it possible to exclude all of "SonarQube community edition server" rules except OWASP related ones?

Comment: You can disable and enable all rules in SonarQube when you log in as Admin. Create a new [Quality Profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles)